# Issue with Doctrine [Symfony 2.8]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have an issue with this array

```
$contenuLigne = array(
    $article->getSousFamille()->getId(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getFournisseurCommun()->getNom(),
    $article->getNom(),
    '="'.$article->getArticleGencod()->first()->getGencod()->getCodeBarreComplet().'"',
    $article->getId(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getReferenceFournisseur(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getCodeProduitGv(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getColisage(),
    ($article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getQuantiteMinimum()) ? $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getQuantiteMinimum() : $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getMinimumCommande(),
    $article->getUniteAchatComplete(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getPrixNet(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getDateDebut()->format('d/m/Y'),
    ($article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixFuturs()->count() > 0 ? $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixFuturs()->first()->getPrixNet() : ''),
    ($article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixFuturs()->count() > 0 ? $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixFuturs()->first()->getDateDebut()->format('d/m/Y') : ''),
    $article->getTauxTva()->getTaux(),
    $article->getPrixVenteConseille(),
    $article->getUniteVenteComplete(),
    $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getStock(),
);
```

Sometimes the lines

Causes errors, how can I make these lines if they do not find a result returns an empty string: " "

```
($article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getQuantiteMinimum()) ? $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getQuantiteMinimum() : $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getMinimumCommande(),
$article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getPrixNet(),
$article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels()->first()->getDateDebut()->format('d/m/Y'),
```

They usually return me this error

### Error: Call to a member function getQuantiteMinimum() on a non-object (500 Internal Server Error)

What can I do and make these lines if they do not find a result returns an empty string: " " ?

The common point among these 3 is that an article may not have a PrixActuels in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The best and simple you can do is to create a [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) :)

This is a small example:

```
<?php

/**
 * Represents an Article value.
 */
final class Article
{
    /**
     * @var Article
     */
    private $article;

    public function __construct(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    public function getSousFamilleId()
    {
        $this->article->getSousFamille()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Suppose all getters are a \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getNameForCommonSupplier()
    {
        $articlePlateforme = $this->article->getArticlePlateforme();

        if ($articlePlateforme instanceof Collection) {
            $fournisseurCommun = $articlePlateforme->first()->getFournisseurCommun();
            if ($fournisseurCommun) {
                $fournisseurCommun->getNom();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a native PHP array representation of the Article.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            $this->getSousFamilleId(),
            $this->getNameForCommonSupplier(),
        ];
    }
}

$contenuLigne = new Article($article);
$contenuLigne->toArray();
```

Now you have all in an object dedicated to get and check your elements.

Comment: Actually my getters are \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection, mais merci pour la réponse je vais essayé de trouver avec ça.

Comment: Cela revient au même ;) C'est juste un exemple à toi de le faire correctement pour toi.

Comment: en fait j'ai assez bien compris ta méthode mais en pratique je peux pas vraiment l'utiliser je pense à moins que je l'adapte, car, $contenuLigne est le résultat d'un remplissage par un foreach qui boucle sur $article, je me retrouve assez coincé à moins que j'ai pas percuter sur la solution

Comment: English guys ;)

Comment: @Veve sorry, i'm a simple french dude i see a french dude i speak french ^^

Comment: No worries, french too, but for the other poor souls hanging here it's better to stay in english :)

Comment: @Veve Baguette for the win.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jepster that you should really consider revising the way that you are building the array.

if you really want to squeeze the null check into that code, you can continue to use ternary operations where you just check whether that entity is null or not, i.e. something like this:

```
$prixActuels = $article->getArticlePlateforme()->first()->getPrixActuels();
$contenuLigne = array(
    ...
    $article->getUniteAchatComplete(),
    $prixActuels ? $prixActuels->first()->getPrixNet() : " ",
    ...
);
```

Comment: I use this array to make a csv file in fact.

Comment: the fact that you use this code to make a csv file bears no relevance to the fact that you should consider to revise how your code is structured